# How to use spark DataFrame groupBy not agg?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I want to get a spark DataFrame group. But I do not know how to do it?

just using spark to groupBy columns. I have searched with google, found that groupBy always used with "agg" function. but I do not need agg, just want to get groups.

if I use Java, such as:

```
package spark.dataframe;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, List<A>> group = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getAge()));
        // group type is what i want to get in spark.
    }
}

class A {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public A(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    //geter
    //seter
}
```

with spark , how to do it ?

```
    //groupBy
    df1.groupBy(df1("Embarked")).count().show()
    df1.groupBy(df1("Embarked")).sum("Fare").show()
    df1.groupBy(df1("Embarked")).agg("Parch" -> "sum").show()

    //groupBy not agg
    ??? todo ???
```

I want to get the answer that using spark solves the problem.

Comment: can you add sample data what you have and what you are looking

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `collect_list`?

Comment: Distinct can be used: df.select("Embarked").distinct